# give a div with "text-align: center" a "text-align: left" for wrapped contents only

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using CSS or JQuery (CSS preferred),

Is it possible to take a div (of 100% width), with its contents centered, and align any contents that wrap to the left?

Imagine a set of icons centered on your browser. If you reduce the width of your browser, instead of having wrapped icons displaying in the center of the second line, I would like them to align left.

I have tried searching here before posting, but couldn't find anything that exactly matches my question.

**Update:**

@Explosion Pills solved it, but here is an updated JSFiddle that addresses browsers other than IE and Chrome by adding `word-wrap: pre-wrap;` to the outer `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/etY4r/2/

Comment: and I have tried so far,  is .....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS (and quite simply).  The outer div can be `text-align: center` and the inner div (containing the icons) `text-align: left` with `display: inline-block`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/etY4r/

The `inline-block` elements are centered in the context of the entire div, but when you decrease the window size enough it will cause the elements to wrap inside of the inner element itself and they are aligned to the left.

Comment: That's an amazingly simple solution. Great thinking!

Comment: @Explosion Pills Thank you very much! I'm glad I asked, for this has got to be the cleanest way...ever!

Comment: I was looking for that myself yesterday. High five!

Comment: @Mattias Buelens In I.E. 10, I'm noticing that that inner div is not respecting the outer div's text-align: center attribute.. any thoughts?

Comment: @Troy I only have IE9.  It works in IE9, but in IE7 mode it does not.  `inline-block` in IE7 only applies to elements that are `display: inline` by default.  Try changing it to a `<span>`

Comment: @Explosion Pills Hmmm... still having the same trouble. Your original method does work in Chrome.

Comment: @Troy sorry, I don't know what to tell you.  It works for me in IE9 and its compatibility modes.  Try: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/etY4r/1/

Comment: @Explosion Pills It's working now. I had my inner div width explicitly set to 100% while testing. Needed to be auto - Oops! It works as expected now on both Chrome and Internet Explorer 10. I'm experiencing the issue still on Opera and Android browser.. ::sigh:: haha

Comment: @Troy well hopefully Chrome will kill "Android Browser," but who uses Opera?  Nobody, that's who

Comment: Fixed my issue with an overall happy workaround. I added 'white-space: pre-wrap' to the outer div and it now works well for all the browsers I've tested it on. Updated JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/etY4r/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.class').css('css property','alignment');
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myClass').css('text-align','left');
   $('.myClass2').css('text-align','center');
   $('.myClass3').css('text-align','right');
});
```

.css() works with any css property in this format :D